# MarionetteJS CompositeView ListenTo undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I am stick now. I get the following error:

```
TypeError: listenTo is undefined    
return listenTo.call(this, evtSource, events, _.bind(callback, context));
```

I do not understand why this error occurs. I dont really know what listenTo expects. When I change `Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView` to `BackboneView` works fine. Any ideas?

See code below:

```
define([
        "jquery",
        "backbone",
        "marionette",
        ],
function($, Backbone, Marionette){

    var CompositeView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
      // The DOM Element associated with this view
      el: ".example",
      // View constructor
      initialize: function() {
          // Calls the view's render method
          this.render();
      },
      // View Event Handlers
      events: {

      },

      // Renders the view's template to the UI
      render: function() {
          // Setting the view's template property using the Underscore template method
          //this.template = _.template('ddd', {});
          // Dynamically updates the UI with the view's template
          this.$el.html('123123123123123123123123');
          // Maintains chainability
          return this;
      }

    });

    // Returns the View class
    return CompositeView;
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update backbone to v0.9.9 or higher.

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/upgradeGuide.md

And

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/changelog.md

Comment: I had this same issue and just got it fixed by upgrading JQuery to 1.9.0 & Backbone to 0.9.10. thanks man.

Comment: This fixed an otherwise inexplicable problem. Thanks much, Derick.

Comment: I had to upgrade from Backbone 0.9.2 to 0.9.10 to fix this for me. When I did this, I started having some problems with the _.bindAll(this) calls that I have been in the habit of putting into the "initialize" functions.

Comment: make sure you update Underscore.js to the latest version as well, Chris Dutrow

Answer (score 2):

`listenTo` is a feature of [Backbone.Events](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo).  Backbone.View and subsequently Marionette.View include the Backbone.Events functionality.  You are calling it as if it were defined globally;  Therefor, you get `listenTo is undefined`.

You can call it with something similar to `myView.listenTo(model, 'change', myView.doSomething)`; or if the current context is the view instance you want to do the listening, `this.listenTo(object, 'eventName', this.doSomething)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I still dont see where exactly listenTo is being called. Can you please clarify? I really appreciate it you looking into this.

Comment: @TeodorTalov the `listenTo` method is overridden by Marionette, and the override calls Backbone's `listenTo`. To me it looks like the only way it can fail is that if `Backbone.Events` doesn't have a `listenTo` method. You closed the other question where I answered, but I think you have the wrong version of Backbone. The call site is on line 537 here, see of yourself: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/lib/backbone.marionette.js

Comment: You are not calling listenTo in your own code? Then @fencliff is probably right, you need to upgrade your version of Backbone. listenTo was added in 0.9.9.  If you are calling it in a Marionnete view you need to use 'this.listenTo()'.